# Display partial unless content_for was defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

What I want to do is, show default sidebar content UNLESS the current view has something else to display in the sidebar.

How would I do this? (rails3)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
content_for?(:sidebar) ? yield(:sidebar) : render(:partial => "shared/default_sidebar")
```